# How to convert a python list to a ymal file in certain format?

Tags: python

I wrote a program with return a list of files with full path such like:

```
f_list = [/mnt/d//NT4_S169_L002_R2_001.fastq.gz,
          /mnt/d//NT4_S169_L002_R1_001.fastq.gz,
          /mnt/d//NT5_S170_L002_R2_001.fastq.gz,
          /mnt/d//NT5_S170_L002_R1_001.fastq.gz]
```

There're about 500+ files and what I wanted is to convert and write it to a yaml file `samples.yaml` such like:

```
-
  id: "NT4_S169"
  R1: "/mnt/d//NT4_S169_L002_R1_001.fastq.gz"
  R2: "/mnt/d//NT4_S169_L002_R2_001.fastq.gz"
-
  id: "NT5_S170"
  R1: "/mnt/d//NT5_S170_L002_R1_001.fastq.gz"
  R2: "/mnt/d//NT5_S170_L002_R2_001.fastq.gz"
```

What's an easy way to realize it?

Comment: Do all the paths have the same length as shown in the example?

Comment: Unfortunately no

Answer (score 1):

Here is a script that should do the trick:

```py
import re

f_list = [
    "/mnt/d//NT4_S169_L002_R2_001.fastq.gz",
    "/mnt/d//NT4_S169_L002_R1_001.fastq.gz",
    "/mnt/d//NT5_S170_L002_R2_001.fastq.gz",
    "/mnt/d//NT5_S170_L002_R1_001.fastq.gz",
]


EXPORT_FILE = "test.yaml"
PATERN_MATCHER = re.compile(
    r"/mnt/d//(?P<id>.+_S\d+)_L\d{3}_(?P<RX>R\d+)_\d{3}.fastq.gz"
)


def build_entry(data: dict):
    return "-" + "\n  ".join([""] + [f'{k}: "{v}"' for k, v in data.items()]) + "\n"


id_list = {}
for f in f_list:
    match = PATERN_MATCHER.match(f)
    if match:
        element = {}
        element["id"] = match.group("id")
        element[match.group("RX")] = f
        if element["id"] in id_list:
            id_list[element["id"]].update(element)
        else:
            id_list[element["id"]] = element

    else:
        print(f"Could not match {f}")

with open(EXPORT_FILE, "w") as f:
    for k, v in id_list.items():
        f.write(build_entry(v))
```

This uses regex to parse the filename, then puts the result in a dictionary so that we can use this to group the files by id.

You could also use the `yaml` module to dump the content of `list(id_list.values())` in a file and obtain the same result, but it is not included in python.

Output :

```yaml
-
  id: "NT4_S169"
  R2: "/mnt/d//NT4_S169_L002_R2_001.fastq.gz"
  R1: "/mnt/d//NT4_S169_L002_R1_001.fastq.gz"
-
  id: "NT5_S170"
  R2: "/mnt/d//NT5_S170_L002_R2_001.fastq.gz"
  R1: "/mnt/d//NT5_S170_L002_R1_001.fastq.gz"
```